# rvm -can't set the version to 1.9.3

Tags: ruby

```
$ ruby -v
$ ruby 1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patchlevel 352) [x86_64-linux]
```

I have:

```
rvm list rubies

rvm rubies

   ree-1.8.7-2011.03 [ x86_64 ]
 * ruby-1.9.3-p125 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default
```

but I get:

```
$ ruby soduko.rb 
nil
nil
```

I can't switch to 1.9.3:

```
rvm use 1.9.3
Gemset '' does not exist, 'rvm gemset create ' first, or append '--create'.

$ rvm gemset create
# Noting(?)

$ rvm gemset create md
Gemset '' does not exist, 'rvm gemset create ' first, or append '--create'.

$ ruby -v
$ ruby 1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patchlevel 352) [x86_64-linux]
```

Comment: Do you have a .rvmrc file in the current directory?  Generally I'd say to use bundler instead of rvm gemsets.  I prefer rbenv.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Probably the new gemset is required to be made and associated together with ruby version. Try this command:

```
rvm use 1.9.3@newgemset --create --default
```

You should also try `rvm use ruby-1.9.3-p125 --default`, sometimes mentioning patch number works (but as far as I've seen this dependency is only seen when working on different patches of same version, still worth a shot)